# Get segments from a Message Hl7

Tags: pentaho, kettle, hapi

I want to retrieve data from each segment `DG1` or `OBX`  from hl7 message, by using pentaho data-integration, in other term, how can i use hl7 input step in kettle to extract data from all repeated segments as `DG1, PV1, OBX`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to extract a specific HL7 segment from your input, take a look at the following output fields of the *HL7 Input* step:

- **StructureName**: Yields the ID of the segment.
- **FieldName**:  Description of the field according to HL7.
- **Coordinates**: Level within each segment.

To tell repeated segments apart, you have to concatenate *StructureName* and *Coordinates*. This can be accomplished by the *Calculator* step. Afterwards the fields in question need to be extracted. Use the *Row denormaliser* step which looks up key-value pairs and assigns them to new fields in the output rows.

Let HL7ID be the new field of the *Calculator* step which adds A and B, where A is *StructureName* and B is *Coordinates*. Within the *Row denormaliser* step, HL7ID will be be key field. Enter your desired segments into be the *Key value*, according to the concatenated value scheme, while the *Value fieldname* column must be assigend to contain the data, i.e. the *Value* output field. Also, the input and output hops of *HL7 Input* are to copy the data, no round robin.

Comment: souds good, I will test it, but i resolved my issue by integrating HAPI java api for HL7 in my transformation.